# How to combine two meshes to average with unequal number of vertices

Tags: transforms

I'd like to combine these two human models into a model that is averaged. But when I use a shape key, it says that selected meshes must have equal numbers of vertices. I don't know if it's appropriate to use this.

So, what should I do first? I'm a beginner and I have to do it by next Monday.
Thank you.

[image]